# How to access and view my own Google+ Photo Album

Tags: google-plus, directory, photo, photos

I am having problems arranging my photos within Google+.

Today I noticed some photos in Google+ but wanted to separate them into 2 photo albums. I created an album, and copied  several photos to it  (I would have preferred to move them across), but am now unable to see this album directly or access it!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are NOT general software/website tech support, and have nothing to go with G+ at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a web service, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using G+ on your computer or your phone?

On the computer, you'll notice a drop-down menu in the top left (under the Google+ logo) that contains things like Home, Profile, People, Photos. Choose **Photos**.

Now the bar across the top of the page has several ways to view your photos, including Highlights, All Photos, and More. Choose **More** and you'll see another drop-down, including the option to view your **Albums**. Click there and you should now see all of your albums on Google+!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this URL https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/yourphotos ?

You can find this url by selecting on photos "top left menu", then selecting "all photos".

You can also see your albums by clicking on "More > Albums" on the top menu.